# Empty input file with ImageMagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I'm using `s3-uploader` in a node project, which uses `node-im-metadata` which builds a `identify` call that throws the error:

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c identify -format "name=
size=%[size]
format=%m
colorspace=%[colorspace]
height=%[height]
width=%[width]
orientation=%[orientation]
" /Users/Path/To/File.jpg
identify: Empty input file `/Users/Path/To/File.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

The thing is, the file is definitely not empty. I can load the file just fine, and have re-downloaded the image multiple times. The process worked *once* but after that it just fails over and over.

If I run the `identify` call directly in the CLI then it works just fine and returns the metadata on the image.